# Rotating the view in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I'm new to working with openGL and am attempting to create a mouse-look camera.

I'm not so much looking for code as much as the method openGL uses for managing roll, pitch, and yaw of the view.  I checked out gluLookAt but it looks to be more for observing an individual object, rather than manipulating the view.

Rotating around the Y axis works fine for yaw.  But when I rotate around X and Z based on the yaw, things go haywire.

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods for rotation, from my personal experience I would suggest arcball rotation, see  [this](http://rainwarrior.thenoos.net/dragon/arcball.html)